# Safari "Find" is slow

Tags: macos, safari, performance

Safari is fast at everything, except "Find".  When I hit command-F, I get the beachball for 5 to 25 seconds (and then the Find bar appears as normal and everything's good again).

I have plenty of free memory, and the system disk is an SSD with plenty of free space, and my CPUs are almost completely idle.

What could be causing this?  Is there something I can do or reset or flush to make it not so slow at this one thing?

Comment: Does it happen in every page, or just in very large ones? In those with a large number of links? Does it happen if you've been in that page for a while?

Comment: Does it happen with other user?

Comment: Thecafremo: It certainly happens with very small and simple pages as much as large ones (e.g., a 5K plain text file with no formatting and no links).

Comment: It definitely can happen when I try to Find immediately after loading a page; not sure about long-lived pages.

Comment: I tried switching to the Guest account just now briefly, and I didn't see it happen, but I didn't give it an exhaustive test.  It doesn't happen 100% of the time, anyway, so it's hard to say that it's unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure you don't have any extensions installed that might be causing issues. Also, you can try "Reset Safari..." and "Empty Cache...", both under the application menu. If neither of these work, you can [download](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/) a new copy of Safari and replace the one currently in your /Applications folder.

After that, make a reservation at your closest Apple Retail Store and see what a Genius says.

Comment: FWIW, emptying the cache had no effect, and I have no Safari extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

With Safari 5, I saw this almost every time I hit command-F.  Since upgrading to Safari 6, I have not seen this happen once, even with the same windows/tabs open as before.  I guess it was a bug in Safari 5 that got fixed!

Comment: I'm un-answering my own question, because upon further use, it's back.  :-(